# Correct Way To Handle Thread Joins in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, join, spawn

So I have a tool written that takes list of items, splits it up into a given number of lists (let's say 10) and then takes those 10 lists and spawns off 10 threads, "EvaluationThreads" (extending threading.thread), and each of those threads evaluates whatever they were supplied to evaluate. When I start each thread I put them all into a list and after spawning them off I have the following code:

```
for th in threadList:
    th.join()
    someTotal = th.resultsAttribute
```

And that's how I handle waiting for all the threads to finish and gathering their information. While this is a working way of waiting for everything to finish and then gathering results I feel like there must be a more elegant way of doing it because these threads could very well finish at different times and if the first one to start finishes last all the ones that finished earlier must wait for that thread to finish before they can be joined. Is there a way to get these threads' information and join them as they finish rather than in the order they were started? I originally figured I would use some sort of callbacks in the threads or something but I'm not sure if there is a more acceptable solution.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: To clarify, my evaluation function is not CPU bound and I'm not trying to distribute the documents among the threads to get it done as quickly as possible, each thread has a fixed about even number of jobs.

Comment: Why is your problem a problem? A thread that's finished but hasn't been joined yet is wasting very few resources (basically, one tiny entry in a table maintained by the OS somewhere in the kernel or userspace).

Comment: I guess it's not exactly a problem, but it just seems like a very inelegant solution, if idling threads isn't a problem that are just waiting to be joined I guess I just wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: A side note: If your "evaluation" operation is CPU-bound, then you are probably not getting much benefit from using threads in this application.  Read about CPython's Global Interpreter Lock (GIL).

Comment: @NedBatchelder: +1 to that. If the data chunks are cheap to copy (or can be generated by the threads themselves instead of passed in), you're probably better off using multiprocessing instead of threading. It also means data is non-shared by default (so if you screw up, it's both more obvious and less catastrophic). And multiprocessing has a Pool class built in, with nice methods to simplify most common idioms.

Comment: They're not even idling threads; they're completed threads. Joining them as soon as possible is nice, but it means you need some way to know which one needs to be joined first. (Or you need a cross-platform equivalent of Win32's WaitForMultipleObjects, which you don't have… although a decent thread group/pool library might use the best implementation available on each platform.)

Comment: @NedBatchelder My evaluation function is not really CPU bound, it sends off a request to a server, I'm just using threading to send multiple requests at once.

Answer (score 2):

For your main question:

If you're doing something more complex than this—or, in particular, if you're doing this repeatedly—you probably want a "thread group" class. There are dozens of them pre-made, but it's pretty trivial to write one yourself if you don't like any of them.

Then, instead of this:

```
threadList = []
for argchunk in splitIntoChunks(values, 10):
  threadList.append(threading.Thread(target=myThreadFunc, args=argchunk))
...
someTotal = 0
for th in threadList:
  th.join()
  someTotal += th.resultsAttribute
```

You can do this:

```
threadGroup = ThreadGroup.ThreadGroup()
for argchunk in splitIntoChunks(values, 10):
  threadGroup.newThread(myThreadFunc, argchunk)
threadGroup.join()
someTotal = sum(th.resultsAttribute for th in threadGroup)
```

Or, maybe even better, a full thread pool library, so you can do this:

```
pool = ThreadPool(10)
for argchunk in splitIntoChunks(values, 100):
  pool.putRequest(myThreadFunc, argchunk)
pool.wait()
```

The advantage here is that you can just as easily have 100 jobs scheduled as appropriate on 10 threads, instead of 10 jobs one per thread, without all the work of maintaining a queue, etc. The disadvantage is that you can't just iterate threads to get the return values, you have to iterate jobs—and ideally, you don't want to keep the jobs alive until the end just so you can iterate them.

Which brings us to your second question, how to get values out of the threads (or jobs). There are many, many ways to do this.

What you've done works. You don't even need any locking.

Using callbacks, as you suggested, also works. But keep in mind that the callback will run on the worker thread, not the main thread, so if it's accessing some global object, you will need some kind of synchronization.

If you're going to synchronize anyway, there may not be any benefit to the callbacks. For example, if all you're trying to do is sum a bunch of values, you can just set `total=[0]`, and have each thread just do `total[0] += myValue` inside a lock. (Of course in this case, it probably makes more sense to just do the summing in the main thread and avoid the lock, but if the work of amalgamating the results is much heftier, that choice may not be as simple.)

You can also use an atomic object of some kind, instead of locking explicitly. For example, the standard Queue.Queue and collections.deque are both atomic, so each thread can just set `q = Queue.Queue()`, then each thread pushes its result by doing `q.push(myValue)`, then after joining you just iterate and sum up the queue's values.

In fact, if each thread is pushing to the queue exactly once, you can just do 10 blocking gets on the queue itself, after which you know that the `group.join()` or `pool.wait()` or whatever will return quickly.

Or you can even push callbacks as jobs onto a queue. Again, you can do 10 blocking gets on the queue, executing the result each time.

If each thread can return multiple objects, they can push a sentinel value or callback onto the queue when they're done, and your main thread keeps popping until it reads 10 sentinels.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Queue to push the information from your threads out as soon as it is available:

Let's say this is your thread:

```
class myThread(threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, results_queue):
       self.results_queue = results_queue
       #other init code here


   def run(self):
       #thread code here

       self.results_queue.put(result) #result is the information you want from the thread
```

And this is your main code:

```
import Queue #or "import queue" in Python 3.x
results_queue = Queue()

#thread init code here

for i in xrange(num_threads_running):
    data = results_queue.get() # queue.get() blocks until some item is available
    #process data as it is made available

#at this point, there is no need to .join(), since all the threads terminate as soon as they put data to the queue.
```

Comment: I believe the underlying system resources only get released when you either explicitly join a thread or the Thread object gets destroyed, which means there _is_ a need to call join(), unless you're about the quit, or you've got a with block or equivalent to manage the Thread objects.

Comment: @abarnert: Do you have a link? I can't find anything about that in the docs. All it says under `Thread.join()` is that it "blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join method is called terminates."

Comment: @abarnert: From the docs, "Other threads can call a thread’s join() method. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called is terminated." This implies that thread termination happens independently of the `join()` method being called.

Comment: Sure, but thread termination only means the thread is no longer being scheduled, not that the underlying resources have been reclaimed. It seems like it would be legitimate for an implementation to make `Thread.join()` do a native `pthread_join` or equivalent (as Jython seems to do), or to automatically join threads as needed and provide some other way for `Thread.join()` to block (as CPython 2.7.3 on POSIX systems seems to do).

Comment: @abarnert: I don't see anything in `Lib\threading.py` under `Thread.join()` or `Thread._delete()` (in Python 3) http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/py3k/Lib/threading.py

Comment: Um… I see almost exactly the same code there as in CPython 2.7.3. It "provides some other way for `Thread.join()` to block" by having a lock on the `Thread` object (`self._block`), and acquiring that lock then checking `self._stopped`. And even if CPython3 worked like Jython, what would that prove? Some implementations do it one way, some the other, therefore both are legal. And even if they _all_ worked like Jython, that would prove the opposite of your point.